# Problem with removing children of a DIV, targetted by EventListener

Tags: javascript, dom, onclick, dom-events

I have a bunch of `<span>`s within a `<div>`, which I want to remove upon click. But the JavaScript doesn't work as intended.

I have also styled my div to us a grid layout, which I don't suspect to be the culprit.

HTML:

```
<div class="collage">
<span class="col01">1</span>
<span class="col02">2</span>
<span class="col03">3</span>
<span class="col04">4</span>
```

JavaScript:

```
var init2 = function () {
    document.querySelectorAll('.span[class^="col"]').addEventListener('click', spanRemover, false)
    var spans = document.querySelectorAll('.collage span')
    function spanRemover (e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
      if (e.target === spans[i]) {
        spans[i].remove()
      }
    }
  }
}
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init2, false)
```

Comment: rather than use addEventListener with function spanRemover, you can directly use document.querySelectorAll with will help you to loop over all the spans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major issue with your code is: you use "span" as class in querySelectorAll selecor so none of your spans get that click handler.

See revised working version

```js
window.addEventListener(
  'DOMContentLoaded',
  () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.collage span').forEach((node) => {
      node.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.target.remove()
      }, false)
    });
  },
  false
);
```

```html
<div class="collage">
  <span class="col01">1</span>
  <span class="col02">2</span>
  <span class="col03">3</span>
  <span class="col04">4</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You answer also helped me to write a neat code.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var init2 = function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.collage span').forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('click', function() {
      this.remove();
    });
  })
}
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init2, false)
```

```html
<div class="collage">
  <span class="col01">1</span>
  <span class="col02">2</span>
  <span class="col03">3</span>
  <span class="col04">4</span
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It did help.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few things you can change:

1. `document.querySelectorAll('.span[class^="col"]')` will return a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) which is a list of elements/nodes which match your query. So, you need to loop through this collection and add your event listener to each node within the collection.
2. `span` is not a class, it is an element. As a result of this, there is no need to use a `.` as a prefix when targeting it with `document.querySelectorAll()`
3. There is no need to loop through all your spans to see which one was clicked. The `e` argument (an object which gives you information about the event) gives you this information by doing `e.target`. You can then remove this using `e.target.remove();`

See example below:

```js
function spanRemover(e) {
  e.target.remove();
}

var init2 = function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('span[class^="col"]').forEach(elem => {
    addEventListener('click', spanRemover, false);
  });
}
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init2, false)
```

```html
<div class="collage">
  <span class="col01">1</span>
  <span class="col02">2</span>
  <span class="col03">3</span>
  <span class="col04">4</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I really appreciate.